# How to not clutter intended casts with static_cast<>?

Tags: c++, casting

have the following struct with one method:

```
struct CaveData
{
    int tunnel_radius;

    int min_cave_edge_points;
    int max_cave_edge_points;

    int min_surface_points;
    int max_surface_points;

    int min_random_points;
    int max_random_points;

    int chunk_seem_connector_cave_range_quotient;
    int chunk_seem_min_points;
    int chunk_seem_max_points;

    inline void addWithFactor(float factor, CaveData & other)
    {
        tunnel_radius += factor * other.tunnel_radius;

        min_cave_edge_points += factor * other.min_cave_edge_points;
        max_cave_edge_points += factor * other.max_cave_edge_points;

        min_surface_points += factor * other.min_surface_points;
        max_surface_points += factor * other.max_surface_points;

        min_random_points += factor * other.min_random_points;
        max_random_points += factor * other.max_random_points;

        chunk_seem_connector_cave_range_quotient += factor * other.chunk_seem_connector_cave_range_quotient;
        chunk_seem_min_points += factor * other.chunk_seem_min_points;
        chunk_seem_max_points += factor * other.chunk_seem_max_points;
    }

};
```

It is intended that all those values are ints and possible inaccuracies are ignored.
However Visual Studio is showing me a literal ton of warnings regarding:
"conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data"

I understand that I can avoid those by adding static_cast() to every line but that feels like cluttering the code (coming from C# and Java) because it just looks like adding another function call.

Is there an alternative way of avoiding the warnings appropriately?

Comment: What does this code accomplish? Please explain in detail, and also make that the title of the question — see [ask]. Also explain why you want the data fields to be integers, what kind of rounding behavior is desired, and why.

Comment: You could make the member variables `float`s themselves.

Comment: Does turning the warning off count as a solution? Personally I think that explicit casting is the way to got for a language like C++.

Comment: (`Is there an alternative` given the current member visibilities, chances are you are screwed for good.)

Comment: The allowable numeric range for `factor` would be helpful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MSVC you can disable the warning for a block of code like the following:

```
    inline void addWithFactor(float factor, CaveData& other)
    {
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4244 ) 
        tunnel_radius += factor * other.tunnel_radius;

        min_cave_edge_points += factor * other.min_cave_edge_points;
        max_cave_edge_points += factor * other.max_cave_edge_points;

        min_surface_points += factor * other.min_surface_points;
        max_surface_points += factor * other.max_surface_points;

        min_random_points += factor * other.min_random_points;
        max_random_points += factor * other.max_random_points;

        chunk_seem_connector_cave_range_quotient += factor * other.chunk_seem_connector_cave_range_quotient;
        chunk_seem_min_points += factor * other.chunk_seem_min_points;
        chunk_seem_max_points += factor * other.chunk_seem_max_points;
#pragma warning( pop )
    }
```

You can also disable the warning for the whole project or a specific file in the settings:

[image]

It might be better to properly cast the conversion.  Using `floor` or `ceil` may add some clutter but it makes your intentions more clear.

You can also consider [`std::lround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) which converts to the nearest integer.